# how to select set columns in a doctrine 2 query

Tags: doctrine-orm

below is my doctrine 2 query. it works.

The only issue for me is that it draws out all the columns in each table: this is an **unnecessary overhead**.

i only want to select certain columns from each table; i tried select a few columns from each table but the query broke.

```
    $qb  =  $this->queryBuilder()
                   ->select(array('u','ph','st'))
                   ->from('BaseModel\Entity\User','u')
                   ->leftJoin('u.statementObject','st')
                   ->leftJoin('u.thePhotoObject','ph')  
      $query = $qb->getQuery();

        $users = $query->getArrayResult();
```

i.e i only want to select the **name** from the **User table.** so the query should look something like:

```
    $qb  =  $this->queryBuilder()
                   ->select(array('u.name','u.name','ph.photoOne','st'))
                   ->from('BaseModel\Entity\User','u')
                   ->leftJoin('u.statementObject','st')
                   ->leftJoin('u.thePhotoObject','ph')  
      $query = $qb->getQuery();

        $users = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $qb = $this->queryBuilder()
           ->select('u.name, ph.photoOne')
           ->from('BaseModel\Entity\User','u')
           ->leftJoin('u.statementObject','st')
           ->leftJoin('u.thePhotoObject','ph')  
 $query = $qb->getQuery();

 $users = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: hey Cristian . thanks very much for that. silly mistake on my part.take care friend